# AdMob banner ad loaded twice when clicked, even in example app by Google

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services, ads, banner

When I click an AdMob banner ad in my Android application, the ad URL is opened and displayed, and then about 5 seconds later, the same URL is opened again.

This is an extremely strange bug I don't know why could be happening. Thought it was my fault, but the same is happening with [this minimal example](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/releases/tag/v2.2) by Google (download, import and run **BannerExample_AdMob.zip**).

It happens all the time, and it's really annoying, as it results in two Chrome tabs with the same ad being shown. And if you don't have a default app for opening http intents, it results in two "Open with..." dialogs being opened with 5 seconds of difference, which feels like something is broken.

This is the very relevant log by AdMob. Only one click was performed on the ad, and as you can see "Ad opening" happens two times without reason:

```
12-13 17:30:27.919 I/Ads﹕ Starting ad request.
12-13 17:30:27.920 I/Ads﹕ Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("XXXXXXXX") to get test ads on this device.
12-13 17:30:30.406 I/Ads﹕ Ad finished loading.
12-13 17:30:30.424 I/Ads﹕ Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
12-13 17:30:35.076 I/Ads﹕ Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
12-13 17:30:40.107 I/Ads﹕ Ad opening.
12-13 17:30:40.119 I/Ads﹕ Ad leaving application.
12-13 17:30:45.286 I/Ads﹕ Ad opening.
12-13 17:30:45.292 I/Ads﹕ Ad leaving application.
12-13 17:30:45.302 I/Ads﹕ Ad closing.
```

I have reproduced this issue both with test and real ads, and in different real devices (Nexus 5 with Android 5.0 and Galaxy S5 with Android 4.4). I have also tried with several different versions of Google Play Services, from 4.x up to the latest 6.x, with the same result.

Any help would be appreciated, including feedback on whether you are able to reproduce the issue with the example app, which takes 2 minutes to try. Huge thanks.

Comment: You need to say which minimal example. You linked to 4 of them.

Comment: I clearly specified to download, import and run **BannerExample_AdMob.zip**, I have make it bold for you.